# Export all data to excel with paginated data using table export?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tableexportjs

```js
var $table = $('#myTabledata'); //My data table
  //console.log($table);
  $('#downloadbutton').click(function() {
    $table.tableExport({
      type: 'csv',
      escape: false,
      exportDataType: 'all',
      refreshOptions: {
      exportDataType: 'all'
    }
  });
});
```

I have the above code. But this code only downloads the data which are rendered in the dom.
I have some paginated data in the second page but that is not getting downloaded in excel. how can i download all my data present in the table using tableexport js? any idea?

Comment: Hi ! Welcome to stackoverflow ! How do you get your data ? If it's from and external source, you might need to make that source generate your CSV.

Comment: I am getting the data through rest api.. With the api data how can i generate csv? 
but currently the variable $TABLE contains the data table with dom data(HTML FORM) and that downloads only dom rendered data.

Comment: Then you need to call your API and make it generate your CSV, because if you have a millions lines, you don't want to send all of that data to your frontend, and then make your frontend generate your CSV. it will take you a year to compute all of that.

Comment: but is there any other option to download the dom rendered with all paginated data?

Comment: use your data source, not what the table shows .. use whatever gets returned from your rest api ( in json ) and convert that to csv https://codepen.io/danny_pule/pen/WRgqNx

Comment: Yeah, make your pagination chunk ( number of result shown at the same time ) bigger, but this will impact performance.